# Tor Browser Log (General Socks Server Failure) ( Bridges Doesn't Work)

Tags: socks

```
4/11/2016 15:24:24 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2016 15:24:24 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2016 15:24:24 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2016 15:24:24 PM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/11/2016 15:24:30 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/11/2016 15:24:30 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 

BIG LIST OF BRIDGES HERE    

4/11/2016 15:42:12 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/11/2016 15:42:12 PM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/11/2016 15:42:12 PM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 


4/12/2016 10:23:37 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:23:43 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/12/2016 10:23:50 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/12/2016 10:23:50 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 

ANOTHER BIG LIST OF BRIDGES HERE    

4/12/2016 10:23:52 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
4/12/2016 10:31:53 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/12/2016 10:31:53 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:31:53 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 


4/12/2016 10:38:45 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:40:18 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:40:18 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:40:18 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/12/2016 10:40:18 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/12/2016 10:40:19 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/12/2016 10:40:20 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
4/12/2016 10:40:40 AM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 3; recommendation warn; host EEF0701D285E2FFA2DB552B1F6C363BB7F93E9A4 at 108.27.91.14:443) 
4/12/2016 10:40:40 AM.800 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
4/12/2016 10:40:40 AM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

Comment: Please don't add addresses of bridges to public forums. By doing so it makes it a little bit easier for people to find out their addresses and block them.

Comment: It looks like the connection to the bridges is being blocked by your ISP. Have a look at using pluggable transports instead: https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en

Comment: In addition to @RichardHorrocks comments I can advise you to look for unlisted bridges - not all of them are public